# Django URL Conflict Despite Specific Views

Tags: python, django

I'm having an issue when someone goes to do a search in my search box (which corresponds to the 'search' view).  The word 'search' is getting picked up by the 'search_category' view and trying to run the query using the word 'search' to match instead.  I think i can see why it is happening--essentially the search and search_category views are both looking for a word after my url.  I'm just confused as to why the actual views are not getting picked up and the URL's are being mixed up?  Here are my views as well:

My urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<letter>[a-zA-Z])/$', views.mineral_letter, name='letter'),
    url(r'^(?P<category>[a-zA-Z\s]+)/$', views.search_category, name='category'),
    url(r'^$', views.mineral_list, name='list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.mineral_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

my views:

```
def mineral_list(request):
    minerals = Mineral.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'minerals/mineral_list.html', {'minerals': minerals})


def mineral_detail(request, pk):
    mineral = Mineral.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'minerals/mineral_detail.html', {'mineral': mineral})


def mineral_letter(request, letter):
    minerals = Mineral.objects.filter(name__istartswith=letter.lower())
    return render(request, 'minerals/mineral_list.html', {'minerals': minerals, 'active_letter':letter})


def search(request):
    term = request.GET.get("q")
    minerals = Mineral.objects.filter(name__icontains=term)
    return render(request, 'minerals/mineral_list.html', {'minerals': minerals})


def search_category(request,category):
    minerals = Mineral.objects.filter(category__icontains=category)
    return render(request,'minerals/mineral_list.html', {'minerals':minerals})
```

Comment: Not a Django pro but moving the search view above the category view might fix it. I think since they're the other way round the category gets picked with the word "search" as category.

Comment: You nailed it.  Thank you!  (Still confused why that should work but i'll go with it!)

Comment: It matters because it stops looking after it found the one matching, so it never actually makes it to the search view. It makes sense, if you think about it, an url has to match one view, otherwise it would be ambiguous, django is forcing you to avoid this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this order:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.mineral_list, name='list'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^(?P<letter>[a-zA-Z])/$', views.mineral_letter, name='letter'),
    url(r'^(?P<category>[a-zA-Z\s]+)/$', views.search_category, name='category'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.mineral_detail, name='detail'),
]
```

Comment: you are definitely right--the re-ordering did the trick.  guess i understand that django uses this ordering to run through the url's one by one, but still confused why it would even matter.